# Centering a single line within a `\parbox` inside a `tabular` cell

Tags: tables, parbox, center

Let us consider the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
        \parbox{6cm}{\vspace{.2cm}%
        \textbf{Title of my cell}\\
        Here stands the written contents of my very own cell.%
        \vspace{.2cm}}
    \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I want to center the title of the cell, `\textbf{Title of my cell}`, while keeping the cell content left-aligned. **How can I achieve that within the `\parbox`?**

I have tried using `\centering` but it affects the whole `\parbox`. I have also tried to enclose the `\centering` command within brackets...

```latex
{\centering\textbf{Title of my cell}}\\
```

... but it does not have any effect.

I seem to recall there was a command which cancels the effect of any previous commands within an enclosed environment `{...}` but I cannot find it.

Comment: `\par` between the `}}` and remove the `\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, I knew changing paragraph sometimes does the trick but I seldom use `\par`. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to end the paragraph in the scope of `\centering` otherwise it does nothing, so use `\par` or a blank line.

```
{\centering\textbf{Title of my cell}\par}
```

Comment: In the kernel there is still `\centerline`  from the relics of PlainTeX!

Comment: @yannisl sure but modern men like myself don't recommend relics. Also if the title gets long this version reacts better